# ¿rotate 90 degrees a bmp in c?

Tags: c, bitmap, bitmapimage

I'm not very good at c, I've been stuck in this problem for days, I found this method on the internet and what I'm looking for is to modify it but it does not work

this is the code that I'm modify

```
   int rotate(PIXEL* original, int rows, int cols, int rotation,
   PIXEL** new, int* newrows, int* newcols)
   {
   int c,r;//counters for rows and columns
   *newrows = cols;
   *newcols = rows;
   //allocating space for the new rotated image
  *new = (PIXEL*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(PIXEL));
  PIXEL *o;
  PIXEL *n;

   for(r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < cols; c++ )
        {
                n = (*new) + (c * rows) + (rows + r + 1 );
                o = ((original) + (r * cols) + c);
                *n = *o;
        }//end of for
      }//end of for 
   return 0;
 }
```

I have a structure of type BMP

```
 typedef struct BMP
 {
char bm[2];             //(2 Bytes) 
unsigned char header[54];
int tamano;             //(4 Bytes) 
int reservado;          //(4 Bytes) 
int offset;             //(4 Bytes) 
int tamanoMetadatos;    //(4 Bytes) 
int alto;               //(4 Bytes) 
int ancho;              //(4 Bytes) 
short int numPlanos;    //(2 Bytes) 
short int profColor;    //(2 Bytes) 
int tipoCompresion;     //(4 Bytes)
int tamEstruc;          //(4 Bytes) 
int pxmh;               //(4 Bytes) 
int pxmv;               //(4 Bytes) 
int colorUsa;           //(4 Bytes)  
int colorImp;           //(4 Bytes) 
unsigned char **pixel;  
long long int size_p;
}BMP;
```

what I want to do is modify the method so that first read the bmp file, make the rotation of 90 degrees and save in a new bmp file

If you could advise me, it would be very helpful, thank you

Comment: Hmmm, `*new = (BMP*)malloc(img->alto*img->ancho*sizeof(BMP));` looks wrong.  Seeing the definition of `BMP` would help.  Even better: a [mcve].

Comment: `new` is not initialized. Maybe you wanted `new` to be `BMP*`?

Comment: I have modified the wording to give a clearer idea of ​​what I am looking for

Comment: Could you describe more about "it does not work"?